# Recover visual handlers of rigging

Tags: rigging, rigify

Following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/XP-LUNTHpuE) for rigify addon I've achieved a rigged human model. It work fine when I grab the handlers that are shown in this picture:

[image]

From a certain point, without knowing what exactly I have done, the handlers disappeared and the armature has taken on the conventional look:

[image]

The elements generated by rigify addon are complex. There is a metarig and a rig, each with multiple layers. I have tried to activate all the layers in both objects and operate with them in the different edition, object and pose modes. I haven't been able to get the handlers back. How can I recover the view of this handlers?

[This is the file](https://pasteall.org/blend/6a460ad2715c43938efff35554d7569f), if needed for review.

Answer (score 2):

Rigify places various bones on different layers to make it easier for the animator to concentrate on only the bones they need at the moment.  You've simply disabled all of the layers with control bones on them:

[image: Screen shot with rig layer controls highlighted]

There are two ways you can enable/disable visibility, both outlined here.  On the right and below, is the traditional Blender "Layers" interface.  If you click on a layer it will toggle between visible and not visible.  You only have one layer enabled and it happens to be the one containing the original skeleton.

The other interface on the right does the same thing, except the buttons are labeled to make it easy to remember what button enables what layer and what is on the layer.  It's also limited to those layers that have control bones, which is why there's no highlighted button even though you have enabled a layer.

You enabled multiple layers on the left by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> when you click on the layers.  On the right, each button is independent of the others.

Comment: Hi marty. Thanks for the answer. These buttons doesn't show the handlers shown in the first picture. Finally I started the rigging process from scratch.

Comment: @aitor Sorry I misunderstood.  It's probably too late now, but don't restart.  Try removing the generated rig and simply regenerating it.